# Сбрасывается значение при использовании маски ввода

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет!

Вопрос в следующем:
есть поле `<input id="pasport">`, к нему я применяю маску ввода `$('#pasport').mask('99 99 - 999999');`.
Все работает замечательно, но если я ввел значение не полностью и сменил фокус или кликнул по другому полю, то все изчезает, поле полностью обнуляется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать или куда копать.

Comment: Так расскажи, как ты решил, пожалуйста ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри документацию, примеры http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ или выкладывай работающий код на jsfiddle, гадать, что же у тебя там с полями, можно долго.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог мне,))) нашел ошибку... как всегда, на самом видном месте. ))